# QFileDialog, how to access network locations

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QFileDialog on Windows 10.  It seems I can only access local resources which includes:

```
My Computer
simon.platten
```

The second is my user folder, in a normal File Explorer I can see other resources such as the Network.

Is it possible to enable access to use other locations in QFileDialog?

I am using Qt 5.9.2

Comment: what qt version are you using?

Comment: The last line of my post.

Comment: Can you try to use getExistingDirectoryUrl? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectoryUrl

Comment: Do you mean when the File dialog is open for users see the path you want? for example network path?

Comment: Yes, When using the regular File Explorer the user can access all the locations accessible to the computer, such as network locations etc.  With QFileDialog the default is just the local file system.